# add http meteor to get website info

Tags: javascript, meteor

I am a complete newbie and trying to create a social website aggregator with meteor, where users can login,post websites,leave comments and rate them.

The app is functional so far, however, I would like it to retrieve some data for the posted websites automatically, ie a title and a description of the site.

I have done the "meteor add http" and tried to build it but it doesn't always work. Sometimes I get the info sometimes not, which is weird. Sometimes I also get the below message in the console "Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/."

Can anyone help and explain why this happens please?

Thank you

**main.js**

```
Template.website_form.events({
    "click .js-toggle-website-form":function(event){
        $("#website_form").toggle('slow');
    },

    "submit .js-save-website-form":function(event){
        if (Meteor.user()) {
            // here is an example of how to get the url out of the form:
            var url = event.target.url.value;
            console.log("The url they entered is: "+url);

            //  put your website saving code in here!
            Meteor.call("getWebsiteData", url, function(error, results) {
                var el = $('<div></div>');
                el.html(results.content);
                var title = $('title', el).text();
                var description = $('meta[name="description"]',el).attr('content');

                Websites.insert({
                    title: title,
                    url: url,
                    description: description,
                    createdOn: new Date(),
                    user: Meteor.user()._id,
                    up: 0,
                    down: 0
                });
            });
        } else {
            alert('You need to be logged in to submit websites!');
        }

        return false; // stop the form submit from reloading the page
    }
});
```

**startup.js**

```
Meteor.methods({
    getWebsiteData: function (url) {
        this.unblock();
        return Meteor.http.call("GET", url, {"npmRequestOptions" : {"gzip" : true}});
    }
});
```

Comment: is the startup.js defined in the server? or both client and server?

Comment: only in the server